# Application just shows spinner - how can I debug?

Tags: silverlight

I have a small silverlight app and when I "play" it, it just hangs in the browser. (Shows the spinner).

How can I debug this and find the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following...

1. Use Fiddler to see if there is any data that is coming/going to the server when you use this application.
2. Use another browser and see if the issue manifests itself
3. If it happens with all the browsers, then you can try capturing a dump of Internet Explorer and try to analyze it for the actual issue.

Comment: +1 for pointing to Fiddler. Look specifically that the XAP is not a 404. You might have the path wrong in your object tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a javascript exception? Open up the developer tools for your browser (F12 in IE and Chrome) to see the specific error message and error code. Once you have those, google them and voila!

Comment: If you'd like to solve the issue you're seeing you should follow my advice. Silverlight projects compile to a XAP that gets deployed as part of an <html> page in an <object> tag. default <object> tags either generated as part of new projects or as part of the bin\TestPage.html contain a javascript onError handler. Long story short: Please look in the Javascript debug console.